# Any advantages to output caching completely static content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

For example, a Contact Us that is simply html.  Pointless? Or still worth setting an OutputCache attribute on the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At practice there is no harm if you cache action output, but you will not have perfomance increasing caused by such caching. If you note the time before action executing and time after result executing by ActionFilter - you will see that rendering static content is very fast operation. Also I think that contact us form is not so often requested as, for example, static site main page. 
If you really want to have perfomance increasing - you should cache dynamic content for short time, for example action that renders block with popular tags on StackOverflow or maybe top questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say pointless. But I'm intrigued to know now. An easy way to find out is to use [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) or [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) pluging for Firefox (or Chrome I think now too) and see if you gain any load time.